# How to type globalThis in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to type `globalThis` but can't figure it out. I thought it was working in the past but now it doesn't.

```js
// globalThis.app.ts

import { Platform } from 'react-native';

globalThis.app = {
  isIos: Platform.OS === 'ios',
};

// Freeze so these can only be defined in this file.
Object.freeze(globalThis.app);
```

```js
// typings/global.d.ts

declare module globalThis {
  const app: {
    isIos: boolean;
  };
}
```

And at the top level...

```js
// App.tsx

import './globalThis.app';

console.log(globalThis.app.isIos);
```

This logs to the console correctly and doesn't display a type error.
But, it also doesn't autocomplete and when I hover over `.app` it gives "any" as the type.

What is the correct way to type globalThis?

Answer (score 0):

Update to:

```
declare module global{

}
```

Use:

```
globalThis.app.isIos
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.